# How can I change the type of database in phpmyadmin from mariadb to mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm using phpmyadmin with xampp on both of my home and work machines. 
Some queries didn't work for me when I was working on one computer, but it worked on another. I checked it and the only difference is in the database server type.

My queries don't work on:

```
Server type: MariaDB
```

[image]

They do work on:

```
Server type: Mysql
```

[image]

How can I change it from MariaDB to Mysql then?

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB are different products. You can't change one into another more than you can change a Toyota into a Ford.

Comment: so the only way is to reinstall xampp now?

Comment: Or you can try and fix those queries, whatever's easier for you. MariaDB is designed to have certain compatibility with MySQL.

Comment: You could also try the latest XAMPP which contains a newer MariaDB (10.1.8).

Comment: What queries don't work?  The two products are 99% compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this difference is here:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

I don't quite know what you queries you are having trouble with but this should get you started.