# Phpmyadmin mysql server choice

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have installed Wamp server.

When I create databases and tables by php and mysql, all are created 
in 'Mariadb'(server choice) in phpMyAdmin.

How to create database and table in 'mysql'(server choice) ?

### Here is my code sample:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create database

$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You want database engine other than MariaDB??

Comment: when i open phpmyadmin it prompts username, password and server choice(mysql or mariadb).(i used earlier version, which has no server choice field).

Comment: you mean this ? have a look
[How can I change the type of database in phpmyadmin from mariadb to mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762560/how-can-i-change-the-type-of-database-in-phpmyadmin-from-mariadb-to-mysql)

Comment: have a look [How can I change the type of database in phpmyadmin from mariadb to mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762560/how-can-i-change-the-type-of-database-in-phpmyadmin-from-mariadb-to-mysql)

Comment: None of your PHP code has anything to do with phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin is just an administration tool. Your own code does not require it. Your code just connects directly to whichever database on whichever server you tell it to. MySQL and MariaDB are basically compatible so PHP's `mysqli_` functions can talk to either one, without any extra configuration. So if you want your code to connect to a specific server/database, then tell it to connect to that server/database. PhpMyAdmin has nothing to do with it.

Comment: P.S. WampServer installs mysql by default, so it's unclear how you ended up with a MariaDB server on there as well, unless you installed it yourself separately? If so then each one (MySQL and MariaDB) should hopefully be running on separate ports, so you'd have to specify the correct port when connecting from PHP. If they're not running on separate ports, then it's likely that one of them isn't running at all, and is failing to start (because generally two services cannot both use the same port at the same time).

Comment: @ADyson recent versions V3.1.? have started installing both MySQL and mariaDB. mariaDB has become the default, probably because MySQL has made some fairly large changes and mariaDB is a slower upgrade curve for those in the beginners group

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, didn't know that - I don't use it personally. The home page of its website appears to imply / suggest it comes with MySQL as standard.

Comment: @ADyson Yes the website is lagging a bit. The company that built it originally have really lost interest now and it is maintained by a really nice French guy, who has put a lot of work into it, some major improvment :)

Comment: @MohamedArifkhanA ok thanks to RiggsFolly, I can clarify my remarks a bit. It seems WampServer will normally install both MySQL and MariaDB. From what I can read online, normally MySQL will run on port 3306 and MariaDB on port 3307. So if you want your PHP code to connect to a specific one of those, you must specify the port number in your `mysqli_connect()` command (it's an optional parameter, if you look in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)). If you don't specify a port, it takes the default port number from your config, which is normally 3306....

Comment: ...But if you say that PHP is always connecting to the mariaDB instance by default, then either you changed some setting so that MariaDB runs on port 3306 instead, or the default mysqli port number in php.ini has been changed. Either way, if you want to connect to MySQL instead, then you need to specify the port number for MySQL in your mysqli_connect() command. (Probably, it's going to be 3307 but you should check your settings first).

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of WAMPServer it has installed both mariaDB and MySQL.

The default has become mariaDB.

In phpMyAdmin you can select the Server you want to be interacting with using the **Server Choice** dropdown

[image]

Alternatively if you know you are not going to use both database servers you can remove one of them and save yourself some memory.

To remove the one you dont want (It can be added back later quite easily) you simple use the WAMPSevrer menus like this

### To remove mariaDB

```
right click wampmanager -> WAMP Settings -> and click on **Allow mariaDB**
```

and give WAMPServer a few seconds to configure and restart and the mariaDB server will have been removed and you will only ever be using MySQL. You will also no get the **Server Choice** dropdown on the phpMyAdmin login page as there will no longer be a choice.

[image]

> To reactivate `mariaDB` later, just reverse the process and click **Allow mariaDB** again and it will be reconfigured and reinstalled, and the green tick will reappear by the name